# Get a non-prime number and its factors below a given maximum

Tags: java, collections, guava

I need to randomly pick a non-prime number below a given maximum, and return all its factors.

I already have all the non-primes and their factors stored in a `Map<Integer, Integer[]>` that is calculated once on startup.

Here's an idea of the implementation:

```
public Pair<Integer, Integer[]> getNonPrimeAndFactors(int maximum)
{
    //Randomly select a non-prime less than maximum
    return new Pair<Integer, Integer[]>(nonPrime, factors.get(nonPrime));
}
```

I'm not really sure what data structure to use in order to pick a key in that `Map` randomly whilst still being less than `maximum`. Picking a random number less than maximum, then iterating down calling `factors.hasKey(randomNumber--)` would be a bit crap.

I'm using Java 7 and Guava, so have Google's collections to pick from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a random key less than the maximum by converting the key set to a `SortedSet` and keep the head set below the maximum value.

When you have such a set, it is then possible to convert it to a list and get a random element by index:

```
public Pair<Integer, Integer[]> getNonPrimeAndFactors(int maximum) {
    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(factors.keySet()).headSet(maximum);
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(set);
    Integer nonPrime = keys.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(keys.size()));
    return new Pair<Integer, Integer[]>(nonPrime, factors.get(nonPrime));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your continued efforts, but this still won't work. There will be gaps in the set. If the maximum is 4, and the random number is 4, then the 4th entry in the list will be 9. which is above the maximum requested.

Comment: @Deejay If the maximum is 4 then the head set will contain only the number 1 so the random number will always be 0 since the random key is selected from the head set.

Comment: Ah, apologies - I hadn't understood what `headSet` actually does.

Comment: @Deejay It returns a view of the set with all the elements that (strictly here) less than the maximum. To include the maximum, you can call `headSet(max, true)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I'm writing a game that is garbage-collection sensitive, I ended up with a `List<Optional<Integer[]>>` and included the primes with an `absent` value, and then did exactly what I said would be rubbish and just iterated down until I get a non-prime. They're so sparse, it's probably the most efficient way.

Comment: @Deejay it probably does not matter in your application but by iterating down the numbers one smaller as a prime have a higher probability (actually double probability) to be chosen than the others.

Comment: @henry Not sure I understand - could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Deejay if the initial random number hits a prime p (not equal to 3), you will end up at the number p-1 which cannot be prime because it is even. The same end result is achived if the initial random number is p-1. So p-1 will be chosen twice as often as another compound number that is not one smaller as a prime.

Answer (score 1):

generate a random number below max, check if it is a non-prime by looking into the table. If it is a prime restart from the beginning, i.e. generate a new random number.

Since the non-primes are much more frequent than the primes this procedure will not take long.

Comment: Thanks - you're right about the low frequency of primes, and I hadn't really thought about the practical implications of that.